# Users can not modify files created by Hudson

Tags: tomcat, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a Hudson deployed on Tomcat.
Tomcat is started as Windows service under user HUDSON_USER.
As result only HUDSON_USER has full access to files created from some Hudson's job.
All other users have only read access.
Is it possible configure Hudson or Tomcat or Windows in order all other users have write access or full access to Hudson's artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would need to right-click on the root folder and of where hudson is placing its build artifacts, then click properties, then click the security tab.  Add the permissions of the users you require, make sure you also click advanced, and check "Inherit from parent the permissions entries that apply to child objects..." and "replace permission entries on all child objects...."

Alternatively, you could host a build repository locally to upload the artifacts to (as Hudson has an option to upload to a repository), and then developers would be able to download the versions they require when they run their local maven builds.  The second option would get my vote though...

For instance: http://archiva.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can access the artifacts over HTTP, e.g. `http://hudson/job/my-project/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip`

I'm not sure why you would want to write directly into Hudson's workspace anyway; read-only access makes sense if you want to move or retrieve the files from a build.

Otherwise if you really do need to change permissions on the filesystem, you could tell Hudson to `chmod` whichever files you want.